# how to run the vbscript from angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vbscript

Files:
1. runvbs.js

```
function vbs () {
  return require ('child_process'). exec ('email.vbs ....... @ gmail.com gmailpassword ....... @ gmail.com Subject "TextBody tratata"',  
function (error, stdout, stderr) {});
};};
vbs ();
```

2. email.vbs

---

```
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments

For I = 0 to 4

Select Case I

Case 0

 emailsendusername = objArgs(I)

Case 1

 emailsendpassword = objArgs(I)

Case 2

 emailTo = objArgs(I)

Case 3

 emailSubject = objArgs(I)

Case 4

 emailTextBody = objArgs(I)

Case Else

End Select

Next

Set emailObj = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

emailObj.From = "ananymus@gmail.com"
emailObj.To = emailTo 

emailObj.Subject  = emailSubject 
emailObj.TextBody = emailTextBody

Set emailConfig = emailObj.Configuration

emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")    = 2  
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1  
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl")      = true 
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername")    = emailsendusername
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword")    = emailsendpassword

emailConfig.Fields.Update

emailObj.Send

If err.number = 0 then Msgbox "Send"
```

node runvbs.js => OK mail sent

how to run a script (email.vbs with parameters) from angularjs?

Comment: From Angular code running in a *web browser*? You can't. You'd have to post a request back to your server and run it there.

Comment: what does it mean?

Comment: You'd have to post a request back to your server and run it there

Comment: The Angular code in the browser runs at the browser on client computers. Those computers don't have direct access to your VB code. The browser code can use ajax to post requests back to your server, and code on your server can run the email code (or anything else). That's how everything works with web software.

Comment: how to run a script on the server?

Comment: That's a broad question. You need some server-side web framework. There are many, many choices.

Comment: If you're just learning how to code your first web applications, then don't use VBScript if at all possible! Go with something more modern. Node.js, PHP, Python, Ruby etc. All these platforms can send emails too.

Comment: can an example on php?

Comment: Browsers just can't execute VB in the first place... All they can execute is Javascript.

Comment: $.ajax({
 url: "mail.php",
 type: "POST",
 data: ({to: ".........@gmail.com", sub: "EMAIL"}),
     dataType: "html",
     beforeSend: funcB,
     success: funcS
});

Comment: <?php
 mail($_POST["to"], $_POST["sub"], "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3"); 
?>

Comment: @Vlad74 If you actually have an answer, then post it as an answer!